# Custom cell button-subview disappears when reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, subview

I'm having some trouble with a custom cell. The deal is that I want certain cells to have a button to the left of the `accessory view`. I achieved this by adding a button to those certain cell's `subview` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`-method. However this caused some trouble when reloading the cells (I have a double-tap to reload-method). Specifically what happened was that the button would flash (disappear, then appear). However, none of the content did the same.

I thought making custom cells where each cell actually have the button, but only certain cells have that button set to visible, would solve it. I tried doing this, but the problem is now that the button disappears totally when reloading. The same does also the checkmark for the `accessory view` if there is one. However, the correct part of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called...

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Here's my `initWithStyle` for the custom cell:

```
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
  // Create the button
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(220, 0, 100, 86)];
  button.tag = 5;
  [self.contentView addSubview:button];  
  self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 
}
return self;
```

And here's the part of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that either hides the button or not:

```
if(item.hasImage) {
  NSLog(@"Made button visible");
  UIView *button = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
  button.hidden = NO;
} else {
  NSLog(@"Made button invisible");
  UIView *button = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
  button.hidden = YES;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code, but I think the easy way to do this is to make two different types of cells, one with the button, and one without, then dequeue the proper one based on your logic.

Comment: Have you checked NSLog("%@",[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5]);

Comment: rdelmar, thanks for the feedback. The problem with this approach is the animations I have. You see, all the cells are actually the same. But when I tap it, it expands and shows the button. I edit the height of the cell, which drags it and keeps the content in the middle. Then I update it, and add the button. This is really smooth. 

I feel if I have two different types of cells, it just isn't as smooth. I could not make it that way at least (I've tried). The text is kinda moving a bit, and there is no way I can make the content actually stay without flashing.

Comment: Sunny Shah, no I have not checked that. I will do it now. 

Ok, so I have the results: When I double tap the cell (and it updates), I receive the same result as when I open it. Except for one thing: the `CALayer` code is different, though it is the same cell and same button. I don't really know what this means, but if you do, it'd be great if you could give me some feedback on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it.

Turns out there were some problems with the `z-index`. I don't quite get it, but when I updated the cell, the button was actually visible, it was just under the cell. So I set the 'z-index' of the button manually, and now I don't have any problems.

Thanks to everyone that gave me feedback!